# Как с помощью IdHTTPServer, ответить на get запрос изображением с Canvas?

Tags: delphi

Нашел компонент генерирующий штрих-коды, у него как у TImage есть свойство Canvas, теперь хочу с его канвы послать изображение, но никак, подскажите, как это реализовать?

**UPD**

```
class function CreateBarcode(SessionId, Id: String): TMemoryStream;
var
  BarCode: TBarCode;
  BarCodeBitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  BarCode := TBarCode.Create(nil);
  BarCode.Code := 'fwuigwgivmcmhiobvy4565b95+tnby5+5nty5+6n656wt56b665y6n';
  BarCodeBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  BarCodeBitmap.width := BarCode.Canvas.ClipRect.Right - BarCode.Canvas.ClipRect.Left;
  BarCodeBitmap.Height := BarCode.Canvas.ClipRect.Bottom - BarCode.Canvas.ClipRect.Top;
  BarCodeBitmap.canvas.CopyRect(BarCodeBitmap.canvas.ClipRect, BarCode.Canvas, BarCode.Canvas.ClipRect);
  BarCodeBitmap.SaveToStream(Result);
end;
```

Comment: Покажите что вы уже сделали самостоятельно и что конкретно у вас не получается. Создаем пустой TBitmap, копируем в него содержимое канвы, сохраняем битмап в MemoryStream, отправляем стрим по HTTP. Какая конкретно часть у вас не получается?

Comment: @kot-da-vinci как Stream в AResponseInfo запихнуть? Добавил в  вопросе

Comment: Разобрался, `AResponseInfo.ContentStream := ` но ошибки все равно вылетают, только они были в момент обращения к компоненту TBarCode

Comment: Если с ошибками обращения к TBarCode еще не разобрались, создавайте новый вопрос, будем разбираться.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci  создал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/750809/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B2-delphi?noredirect=1#comment1157403_750809