# Как генерировать штрих-коды в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, штрихкод

Есть билет с данными(номер и т.д.), как, а главное чем, можно создать штрих-код для этого билета в Delphi?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008544/barcode-generation-libraries-for-delphi

Comment: 1. определить алгоритм штиха (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%88%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2). 2. Найти реализацию в сети (гуглом).

Comment: Видел где-то в сети xls файл с vb- скриптом, который генерирует много стандартов штиха.

Comment: @nick_n_a подходит Code 128. А вот найти реализацию, пока не выходит, просмотрел кучу компонент

Comment: Вот хорошее описание http://www.webcitation.org/66t8IbBVl?url=http://tradepilot.ru/goods-marks/code128 на счёт готового - не знаю.

Comment: В Fast Report есть. Не знаю сколько он стоит и стоит ли его только ради штрих кода покупать.

Comment: @AlbertFomin в Fast Report есть TfrxBarCodObject, но как с ним работать?

Comment: @teran сразу не заметил ваш комментарий, посмотрел вроде везде или я плохо ищу или бесплатных нет. Пока триальной пользуюсь

Comment: @ArtGrek13 TfrxBarCodeView я использовал,  нужно кинуть этот компонент на форму и в свойствах указать значение (двойной клик в редакторе), вылезет форма в которой спроситься тип штрих кода , ориентация, значение текста. В поле "Код" - переменную со значением указать нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делал на Delphi XE8 Fast Report 5.0

```
uses
  ...
  frxBarcode, // для TfrxBarCodeView
  frxBarcod;  // для присвоения BarType нужного типа штрих-кода

function TForm1.CreateBarcode(): TMemoryStream;
var
  BarStream: TMemoryStream;
  BarImage: TImage;
  BarCode: TfrxBarCodeView;
begin
  BarStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    BarImage := TImage.Create(nil);
    try
      BarCode := TfrxBarCodeView.Create(nil);
      try
        BarCode.BarType := bcCode128;
        BarCode.Text := 'some barcode text';
        BarCode.ShowText := False;
        BarCode.Height := 89;
        // прорисовываем штрих-код на канву картинки с 
        // масштабХ 1, маштабУ 1, смешениеХ 0, смещениеУ 0
        BarCode.Draw(BarImage.Canvas, 1, 1, 0, 0);
        BarImage.Picture.Bitmap.SaveToStream(BarStream);
      finally
        FreeAndNil(BarCode);
      end;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(BarImage);
    end;
  finally
    Result := BarStream;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

сама процедура перевода 13-ти цифр в последовательность EAN13:

```
procedure ean13generate(var barcode:string);
var
   tableA: boolean;
   codeBarreS: string;
   i, firstI: integer;
begin
   if barcode.Length = 13 then
      begin
        //первое число берём как есть, а второе из таблицыА
        codeBarreS:=barcode.Substring(0,1) + Chr(65 + StrToInt(barcode.Substring(1,1)));
        firstI := StrToInt(barcode.Substring(0,1));
        for i:= 2 to 6 do
        begin
           tableA := false;
           case i of
           2:
             begin
                 case firstI of
                 0,1,2,3:
                   begin
                     tableA := true;
                   end;
                 end;
             end;
           3:
             begin
                  case firstI of
                 0,4,7,8:
                   begin
                     tableA := true;
                   end;
                 end;
             end;
           4:
             begin
                 case firstI of
                 0,1,4,5,9:
                   begin
                     tableA := true;
                   end;
                 end;
             end;
           5:
             begin
                 case firstI of
                 0,2,5,6,7:
                   begin
                     tableA := true;
                   end;
                 end;
             end;
           6:
             begin
                  case firstI of
                 0,3,6,8,9:
                   begin
                     tableA := true;
                   end;
                 end;
             end;
      end;
           if tableA=true
           then begin
             try
               codeBarreS := codeBarreS + Chr(65 + StrToInt(barcode.Substring(i,1)))
             finally
                form1.edit2.text := codeBarreS + ' + finally_1';
             end;

           end

           else;
              try
               codeBarreS := codeBarreS + Chr(75 + StrToInt(barcode.Substring(i,1)));
             finally
                form1.edit2.text := codeBarreS + ' + finally_2';
             end;

end;
        codeBarreS:= codeBarreS + '*'; // добавляем разделитель
        for i := 7 to 12 do
        begin

              //ShowMessage(barcode.Substring(i,1));
              codeBarreS := codeBarreS + Chr(97 + StrToInt(barcode.Substring(i,1)));
        end;
       codeBarreS := codeBarreS + '+'; // добавляем прерывающий символ
      form1.edit2.text := codeBarreS;
      end;

end;
```

Comment: Почему вы не добавляете в уже данный ответ, а даёте новый?

Comment: Потому что я не умею пользоваться этими редакторами на форумах.

Comment: Тогда надо учится, сложного тут ничего нет. Под каждым сообщением есть кнопка "править". И ещё, данный сайт не является форумом.

Answer (score -1):

Написал такую простую процедуру для генерации Баркода (скажу честно - переписал на Delphi c Visual Basic) по стандарту EAN13 для организации (собственный баркод для товара) без функции расчёта контрольного числа Баркода (её можно найти в Инете или я потом могу скинуть , если надо) :

```
procedure barcodeGenerator(memo: TMemo; iFirst: integer);
var
  sPrefix, sBuffer, sBarcode: string;
  i: integer;
begin
  sPrefix := '2000'; // префикс баркода и свободные числа
  sBuffer := IntToStr(i + iFirst - 1);

  sBarcode := sPrefix;
  //заполняем Баркод нулями для длины
  while (sbarcode.Length + sBuffer.Length < 12) do
    sBarcode := sBarcode + '0';

  sBarcode := sBarcode + sBuffer;

  memo.Lines.Add(sBarcode);
end;
```

Comment: Тут сразу несколько проблем, как с кодом (неинициализированные переменные, лишние конструкции, форматирование (часть поправил)), так и с ответом по сути - вопрос не в том как сделать строчку из 13 цифр, а в том как получить рисунок штрих-кода.

Comment: Ну тогда сделать из этих 13-ти цифр последовательность символов EAN13 и потом её преобразовать с штрих-код. Я написал ещё одну процедуру, которая преобразовывает в последовательность символов. Потом этот код EAN13 можно вставить в какой-нибудь EXCEL-файл с и применить шрифт code-ean13.font (ну или как он там называется).